# how can I move a background proces to foreground

Tags: c, linux, shell, unix, foreground

I want to move a process  to foreground. I know the bash I have to use fg but in c how can I implement this ? any suggestion as a starting point for me?

Comment: What does the *foreground* mean from a non-shell program?

Comment: I'm implementing my own shell with c programming @ScottHunter

Comment: Do you want to make your program run as a daemon?

Comment: When you start a C program from the shell you run it in foreground so it is not clear what you mean. How do you start your program and what you want to achive?

Comment: I don't want to run a daemon @GuillaumeLegrain

Comment: Can you give example code. Perhaps you are using a fork, send the child to the background and want to have a command to the parent to switch to the child. If this is roughly your question, please edit your question.

Comment: yes I use fork and with "&" I send to background. I store background process in a linked list and now I want to move from this linked list to foreground when the user prompt "fg"  @WalterA

Answer (score 1):

Background and foreground is just a matter of who receives the input the user types into the terminal. The processes are still scheduled by the operating system.

If you put a process into background from within your shell, you must disconnect the standard input file descriptor of this process from the terminal of the shell.
The outputs can still go to the terminal (depends on your expected behaviour of the shell).

To put the process back into foreground you have to reconnect the standard input back to the terminal, so that, the process can receive input from it, i.e, from the user again.

Answer (score 0):

The best entry point is `tcsetpgrp`, a function that let you set a process group as the receiver of controls from terminal and be authorized to get inputs a do outputs to and from the terminal.

For all of this to work properly, you also need to have a look at `setsid` to set a session.

Subsequent interesting function is `setpgid` to build process groups.